# How to prove this claim about bipartite graphs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, bipartite-graphs

```
If G is a connected, planar, bipartite graph with number of Edges >= 4, 
then prove that (Number of Edges) <= 2(Number of Vertices) - 4
```

Can someone help me out? I'm just doing some practice problems and am sort of behind in this class. A step by step explanation of the proof and what i need to solve it would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I tried this based on a property of Planar graphs

```
  -For all planar graphs with >=4 edges, E <= 3v-6
  -This implies 3V-6 <= 2V - 4
```

But this is obviously wrong. I feel like i might be in the right direction?

Comment: The inequality does not follow. If $a \leq b$ and $a \leq c$, this does not necessarily mean that $b \leq c$, nor that $c \leq b$.

Comment: I know. I was thinking that. SHould i use Eulers formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [second planarity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Other_planarity_criteria), which states $e \leq 2v - 4$ if there are no three-cycles in the graph. A cycle of length $3$ would contradict the bipartite property of the graph.

EDIT: You can prove the second planarity theorem quickly using the Euler planarity characteristic $v - e + f = 2$.

We know that, if there are no cycles of length $3$, every face must consist of at least four edges, and every edge must have two faces: $2e \geq 4f$. Hence, $2 - v = f - e\leq \frac{1}{2} e  - e = -\frac{1}{2} e$

Note, since $2 - v \leq -\frac{1}{2} e$, we have $e \leq 2v - 4$.

Comment: But that's what we are trying to prove. We are trying to prove the second planarity theorom

Comment: Where does the 1/2e - e come from?